# Django-wiki not syncing database

Tags: python, django, project, wiki

On a brand new project that's sole purpose is to test if I'm doing everything correct, this https://github.com/benjaoming/django-wiki module works fine, bet as I'm trying to attach it to my main app, it shows this error when I'm runing `python manage.py syncdb`: `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: ImportError wiki.plugins.attachments: No module named plugins.attachments` - can you please tell me why and how can I fix that?

Also - why did I get a downvote for this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to list the plugins in your INSTALLED_APPS as well, see:

https://github.com/benjaoming/django-wiki#configure-settingsinstalled_apps

So your INSTALLED_APPS should contain, in this order:

```
'django.contrib.humanize',
'south',
'django_notify',
'mptt',
'sekizai',
'sorl.thumbnail',
'wiki',
'wiki.plugins.attachments',
'wiki.plugins.notifications',
'wiki.plugins.images',
'wiki.plugins.macros',
```

EDIT:

I'd suggest re-installing the wiki package.

```
# pip uninstall wiki
# pip install wiki
```

Comment: I know, that's how I did it in both - the test project as well as in the real project, the test worked out fine, bet the real one - didn't.

Comment: Try to reinstall the wiki package on the machine that runs the real project.